# Wrapping div around floating objects?

Tags: html, css

Just a forewarning, I am aware for the most part of how float works, and I understand that a div will not wrap floating objects. However, a came across a section of code on w3 schools and I'm a bit confused. Essentially, they use a ul and they float the li items, but the ul wraps to fit the height of the list items. If i were to do the same thing with a div, the div and the list items would not line up, I'm just curious as to why it works with the ul but not with div? 
the code can be found here
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS for the `ul` in that example contains `overflow: hidden;`. This makes an element wrap floating child elements. There's no difference in that respect whether it's a `ul` or `div`.

Comment: oh okay awesome, i appreciate it